# Custom Python Expression Functions (QGIS Tutorial)

Tags: qgis, python, references, expression, qgis-custom-function

I'm having trouble finishing the QGIS tutorial for Using Custom Python Expression Functions: http://www.qgistutorials.com/de/docs/custom_python_functions.html

I get to the point where I write the script in the function editor, but when I want to use the function in an expression it looks different and doesn't work.

Screenshot 1 is what it looks like in the tutorial, screenshot 2 is my result when I double click on the custom function. The code is the same, I copy pasted it into the functions editor. When I write the exact same expression as in the tutorial it says 'expression invalid' (screenshot 3).

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Have you tried using this expression:     GetUtmZone('40N')

Comment: Yes I did, but it also says 'invalid expression' (see screenshot 4)

Comment: Did you register the function after writing it by clicking Run Script button?

Comment: Well, the thing is, I don't have a Run Script button like the one in the tutorial. I posted another screenshot of what my function editor looks like. I only have a "Load" button. I clicked that one, it made the function appear under "Custom" in the expression part.

Comment: Click on More Info it will tell you what is wrong.

Comment: I did, but unfortunately I have no idea what the errors (see screenshot 6) mean or how to fix them. Can't really find any useful information on that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this if you want to Select by Expression

`GetUtmZone() = '40N'`

If you just need to get the return value from the function you can just do

`GetUtmZone()`

The `$` prefix used to be used for functions that took no arguments however that is no longer used in later versions, the version in the tutorial is a older QGIS version that still supported that format.